# What is the place of early pragmatism in analytic philosophy?

Tags: analytic-philosophy, pragmatism

What is the place of early pragmatism (James, Dewey, Peirce) in analytic philosophy?

To break down the question: is early pragmatism considered as part of analytic philosophy; does it have a lot of influence on this movement; do a lot of analytic philosophers consider themselves as pragmatist?

Comment: Not so much... The "first wave" traces back to Frege/Russell/Wittgenstein. For some influence of Pragmatism you have to see the American "second wave": Quine and Putnam. See e.g. Cheryl Misa's *Pragmatism and Analytic Philosophy* into Michael Beaney (editor), [The Oxford Handbook of the History of Analytic Philosophy (2013)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Oxford_Handbook_of_the_History_of_An/ZFTsrQEACAAJ).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If you would like to copy past your comments onto an answer, I would be pleased to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so much...

The "first wave" traces back to Frege/Russell/Wittgenstein.
For some influence of Pragmatism you have to see the American "second wave": Quine and Putnam.
See e.g. Cheryl Misa's Pragmatism and Analytic Philosophy into Michael Beaney (editor), [The Oxford Handbook of the History of Analytic Philosophy (2013)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Oxford_Handbook_of_the_History_of_An/ZFTsrQEACAAJ).

See first para of the above chapter:

> "Richard Rorty (1995) articulates and upholds the received view of the relationship between pragmatism and analytic philosophy: Along about 1945, American philosophers were, for better or worse, bored with Dewey, and thus with pragmatism. They were sick of being told that pragmatism was the philosophy of American democracy, that Dewey was the great American intellectual figure of their century, and the like.They wanted something new, something they could get their philosophical teeth into. What showed up, thanks to Hitler and various other historical contingencies, was logical empiricism, an early version of what we now call ‘analytic philosophy’."

For Quine, see e.g. [Quine and Pragmatism](https://petergodfreysmith.com/Quine_Pragmatism_PGS_2013_FD.pdf).